# I want to add an image to a specific cell in my table within my aspx class

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I want to add an image to a particular cell in a table within my aspx class. Right now I have an if statement which changes the colour of the cell, I want another if statement which adds an image to that same cell. Any ideas how to do this?

```
public partial class FutureDelivery : System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage
{

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
        errormsg.Text = "";
        FutureDeliveryModel theModel = (FutureDeliveryModel)ViewData["FutureDelivery"];
      // litSite.Text = Site.getSite();
        //DataTable StockTable = (DataTable)ViewData["Future"];
        DataTable StockTable =  theModel.GetFuture();
        DataView StockView = StockTable.DefaultView;
        StringBuilder SB = new StringBuilder();
        SB.Append("<table class=\"display\" id=\"dt\" style=\"align: left; width: 99%;\" ");
        SB.Append("rules=\"all\" border=\"1px\" ");
        SB.Append("cellspacing=\"0px\" cellpadding=\"4px\">");

        SB.Append("<thead>");
        SB.Append("<tr></tr>");
        SB.Append("<tr style=\"background-color: Silver; color: #212121; ");
        SB.Append("font-weight: bold\">");
        // Header 
        foreach (DataColumn aColumn in StockTable.Columns)
        {
            SB.Append("<td>");
            SB.Append(aColumn.ColumnName);
            SB.Append("</td>");
        }
        SB.Append("</tr>");
        SB.Append("</thead>");
        SB.Append("<tbody>");
        string Site = " ";
        //detail
        foreach (DataRowView aRowView in StockView)
  {
            int qty = 0;
            int export = 0;



            SB.Append("<tr>");
            foreach (DataColumn aColumn in StockTable.Columns)
            {

                SB.Append("<td style=\"text-align: left\"");
                if (aColumn.ColumnName.ToString().Equals("Site"))
                {
           //         SB.Append("<a href=\"");
           //         SB.Append(ApplicationUtility.FormatURL("/Stock/FutureDelivery")); 
           //         SB.Append("?Site=");
                    SB.Append(">");
                    Site = aRowView["Site"].ToString();
                    SB.Append(Site);

                //    SB.Append(aRowView[aColumn.ColumnName].ToString());
          //          SB.Append("</a>"); 
                }
                else
                {
                    if (aColumn.ColumnName.ToString().Equals("Quantity")) qty = Convert.ToInt32(aRowView["Quantity"].ToString());

     if (aColumn.ColumnName.ToString().Equals("Export Quantity"))
                    {
   export = Convert.ToInt32(aRowView["Export Quantity"].ToString());

    if (export != qty && export != 0) SB.Append(" BGCOLOR=\"#00ff00\" ");

                    }

                    SB.Append(">");


                    if (aColumn.ColumnName.ToString().Equals("Export Quantity"))
                    {
                        if (export == 0)
                        {
                            SB.Append(" ");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            SB.Append(aRowView[aColumn.ColumnName].ToString());
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        SB.Append(aRowView[aColumn.ColumnName].ToString());
                    }

                }
                SB.Append("</td>");
            }
            SB.Append("</tr>");
        }


        SB.Append("</tbody>");
        SB.Append("</table>");

        litFutureDeliveryDetail.Text = SB.ToString();
        linkBackToMainPage.NavigateUrl = ApplicationUtility.FormatURL("/Stock/Login?action=out");
        linkBack.NavigateUrl = (String)Session["BACKURL"];
        linkUserMaint.NavigateUrl = ApplicationUtility.FormatURL("/Stock/UserMaint");
        screentitle.Text = "Future Deliveries";
        if (theModel.GetErrorMessage().Trim() != "")
        {
            StringBuilder ES = new StringBuilder();
            ES.Append("<table border=1><tr><td  class=\"ErrorText\">");
            ES.Append(theModel.GetErrorMessage().ToString());
            ES.Append("</td></tr></table>");
            errormsg.Text = ES.ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            errormsg.Text = " ";
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be you simply need a string append like follows,

```
if(condition){
    sb.Append("<img src=\"images/pic.jpg\" alt=\"Sample Photo\" />");
}
```

Where `images/pic.jpg` is the path to image.

Comment: @Karan Ramchandani - It's simply actually :) Mark the answer as correct if you think it's the best answer ;)